# Is there any way to identify the error returned by a SQL Server stored procedure in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, sql-server

**Scenario**: executing a stored procedure to insert row into a table

**Output**: normal, should insert record as set in SQL statement

**Failure case**: if unique key is violated, it should not update and throw error

All the above steps are working when manually executed in Azure Studio. The same when integrated with NodeJS by using ASYNC call, it works only for the +ve test case; which is a for fresh new record inserted and ***when the duplicate is inserted, the recordset.length is seen as **undefined*****

This undefined is visible in **6.3.1** and not in the earlier version of **6.2.3**

Now in **6.3.1**, I could find only an option of using **returnValue**. Does anyone know other features available to get notified of the error. Below is the output

If it's successful, I get the result as

```
{
  recordsets: [],
  recordset: undefined,
  output: {},
  rowsAffected: [],
  returnValue: 0
}
```

Comment: You'll need to post code for anyone to comment.  But _generally_ you may need to consume rowcount messages or resultsets before you see the error in the TDS stream.

Comment: You'll need to return the correct output from the catch block.  It might help if you posted the SQL

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put your INSERT/UPDATE inside a TRY-CATCH block, then return a specific integer ir a RAISE ERROR. Also, put It on a transaction to rollback on the CATCH block.

Comment: I had done that too.. below is the output.. but the simple solution [result.recordset] has been turned out to be too complicated. that was the only reason why i raised this

{
  recordsets: [ [ [Object] ] ],
  recordset: [
    {
      ErrorNumber: 2627,
      ErrorSeverity: 14,
      ErrorState: 1,
      ErrorProcedure: 'dbo.sp_employee',
      ErrorLine: 22,
      ErrorMessage: "Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UQ__emplyeetemp__41A559E11815AB5C'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.employee'. The duplicate key value is (10001)."
    }

Comment: Did you tried to return Just a SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE() ?

Comment: Yes, what you said is correct. I did only SELECT

SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,
                        ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity,
                        ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState,
                        ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure,
                        ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine,
                        ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage